# MVC EditorFor with compound model type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editorfor

I would like to send a delegate or a command object as argument to an EditorFor along with the model object. I could use viewdata to send it with, but I would very much like it *strongly typed*. Is there any reasonable way to do this?

This is roughly what I'd like to be able to do in an editor template:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Pair<MyModelType, TheDelegate>>" %>
```

But how could I add my delegate to an expression such as this?

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyModelTypeField, "ThatEditor") %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a strongly typed manner unless you modify your view model and have the controller pass the necessary information. So

```
public class MyModelTypeWithDelegate
{
    public MyModelType MyModelType { get; set; }
    public TheDelegate MyModelTypeDelegate { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyModelTypeWithDelegate MyModelTypeWithDelegate { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyModelTypeWithDelegate, "ThatEditor") %>
```

The other possibility is to pass it as additional viewdata but it won't be strongly typed:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyModelTypeField, "ThatEditor", new { TheDelegate = someDelegate }) %>
```

and then inside your editor template:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyModelType>" %>
<%
    var del = (TheDelegate)ViewData["TheDelegate"];
%>
```

Comment: I was hoping I could create a new instance of another type in the m=>m.MyModelTypeField expression. Thanks for letting me know!